# Django model in combination with the admin site

Tags: mysql, django

I got these tables in the models file:

```
class ingredient (models.Model):
    ingredient_row_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    ingredient_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ingredient_name)

class receip(models.Model):
    receip_row_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    receip_id=models.IntegerField()
    receip_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    receip_ingredient=models.ForeignKey(ingredient)
    receip_ingredient_quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.receip_name)

class prod(models.Model):
    product_row_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    product_receip=models.ForeignKey(receip)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prod_name)
```

What I want to do is to define a product which is done by a specific receip. In this receip is given the quantity of each ingredient.

Now I want to combine all these. Lets say i have in ingredient a Cherry and Water.

Now the receip is cherry water. So I got  this in receip:
[image]

Now I want to combine this in the admin Panel[image]

As you can see I can choose between two "receips" because it refers to the receip_row_id not to the receip_id.

So is there any way to "combine" these to so that I only got one in the admin site. Maybe I need to change my models.py to smth else or optimize the admin.py .

Somebody got an idea?
Greetings

Comment: If you use the receipt id instead of receipt row id, then how do you want to determine which one to use (because there will of course be more than 1 with that id)?

Comment: Looks to my like you have added the _Water Cherry_ recipe twice to the database (= you may have created new recipe instances for each ingredient). That would explain why you see the receipe twice in the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the reference to the product in receip. This works for me I guess.
So it looks like this now:

```
class ingredient (models.Model):
ingredient_row_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
ingredient_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.ingredient_name)

class receip(models.Model):
receip_row_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
receip_id=models.IntegerField()
receip_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
receip_ingredient=models.ForeignKey(ingredient)
receip_ingredient_quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
receip_product=models.ForeignKey(prod)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.receip_name)

class prod(models.Model):
product_row_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
product_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.prod_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer, but:

- you dont have to specify a field with `primary_key` property, Django autogenerates a field `id` (which has this property) for you automatically. I am not sure why do you define these fields in your model explicitly, but I'd say you can remove them.
- `ForeignKey` always refers to the primary key of the other model. So there's not way for you how to "combine" these fields - they are basically two different records and the app has no way how to find out they can be combined. Looks like your DB schema is not compatible with the thing you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Im aware of that primary_key thing but i like to define it myself. Dont know if that is a bad style or smth. Yeah maybe I relly need to redifine my DB schema. I thought maybe someone has an idea. Thanks again :)